# Type-hint an object that implements two interfaces

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to type hint that an object implements two different interfaces? Perhaps similar to the fake `my_function` example below.

```
   class SomeLibraryClass(InterfaceA, InterfaceB):
       ...

   def my_function(obj: Multiple[InterfaceA, InterfaceB]):
      obj.do_interface_a_stuff()
      obj.do_interface_b_stuff()
```

I can't modify `SomeLibraryClass`. I could define `class AB(InterfaceA, InterfaceB)` but the type checking tools I use will still flag `SomeLibraryClass` as not implementing `AB`. This solution also leads to a proliferation of classes defining all combinations of interfaces we want to type hint about. (It may be this is the 'the correct way' to do things, in which case that would be the answer!)

Answer (score 0):

I still don't think this can be done directly as you want. But with Protocols, you can get some of the way there, as long as you know which methods you want to call.

```py
from typing import Protocol

class IABStuff(Protocol):
    def do_interface_a_stuff(self):
        pass

    def do_interface_b_stuff(self):
        pass


def my_function(obj: IABStuff):
      obj.do_interface_a_stuff()
      obj.do_interface_b_stuff()
```